# How would I call a function in an object

Tags: javascript

How would I call a function that alerts inside of an object? Here's what I've got so far:

```
function ObjectAlert(a,b,c){
  var obj = {};
  obj.name = a;
  obj.location = b;
  obj.shout= function (){alert(c);};
  return obj;

}
ObjectAlert("jake","here","alert");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code. Hope it will fulfill your requirement..

```
function ObjectAlert(a,b,c){
  var obj = {};
  obj.name = a;
  obj.location = b;
  obj.shout= function (){alert(c);};
  return obj.shout();

}
ObjectAlert("jake","here","alert");
```

Or, you can try the following..

```
function ObjectAlert(a,b,c){
  var obj = {};
  obj.name = a;
  obj.location = b;
  obj.shout= function (){alert(c);};
  return obj;

}
ObjectAlert("jake","here","alert").shout();
```

And, also can try this..

```
function ObjectAlert(a,b,c){
  var obj = {};
  obj.name = a;
  obj.location = b;
  obj.shout= function (){alert(c);};
  return obj;

}
var shout = ObjectAlert("jake","here","alert");
shout.shout();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ObjectAlert("jake","here","alert").shout();
```

or

```
var OA = ObjectAlert("jake","here","alert");
OA.shout();
```

?

Answer (score 0):

```
function ObjectAlert(a,b,c){
  var obj = {};
  obj.name = a;
  obj.location = b;
  obj.shout= function (){alert(c);};
  return obj;   
}

var myAlert = ObjectAlert("jake","here","alert");
myAlert.shout();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var object = new ObjectAlert("jake","here","alert");
object.shout();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply like

```
var test = ObjectAlert("this","is","alert");
test.shout();
```

or even better/direct

```
ObjectAlert("this","is","alert").shout();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
var obj = ObjectAlert('jake', 'here', 'alert');
obj.shout();
```